Why is $\{\omega \in \Omega | lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=1\}$ in the tail $\sigma$-Algebra?
On a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ I have a series of random variables $ X_n, n \geq 1$ and  $ \mathcal{A}_{\infty}:=\limsup_k \sigma(X_k)$ denotes the corresponding tail $\sigma$-field.
I want to show that $B:=\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=1\} \in \mathcal{A}_{\infty}$ .
My thought was to use the fact that $T:\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}, T:=\mathbb{1}_{\{X_n \text{ converges}\}}$ is $\mathcal{A}_{\infty}-\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ -measurable, but now I struggle to continue the proof.
What I know is:

since $T$ is measurable the preimage of measurable sets in $\mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$ are $\mathcal{A}_{\infty}$-measurable
$T(B)=1$,  $\ T^{-1}(\{1\})=\{X_n \text{ converges}\}$
$\limsup_n (\{X_n^{-1}(A)\mid A\ \text{measurable}\}) \in \mathcal{A}_{\infty}$

How do I put this together to proof that $B\in\mathcal{A}_{\infty}$?
Note: This is no assignment, I am looking at some old exercises to study for an exam and for this one I don't have the solutions to help.

The tail sigma algebra is the intersection of the sigma algebras $\sigma(X_k, X_{k+1},...)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Intuitively, we use the fact that convergence doesn't depend on the first elements of the sequence. Formally, let $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then:
$\{\omega\in\Omega: X_n(\omega)\to 1\}=$
$=\{\omega\in\Omega: \forall\ (\epsilon\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,\infty)) \ \exists (n_0\geq k) \ \forall (n\geq n_0) \ [\ 1-\epsilon<X_n(\omega)<1+\epsilon \ ]\}= $
$=\bigcap\limits_{\epsilon\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,\infty)}\bigcup\limits_{n_0=k}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{n=n_0}^{\infty} X_n^{-1}(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$
And this is an element of $\sigma(X_k, X_{k+1},...)$, because it is obtained by countable intersections and unions of elements in this sigma algebra. That's why we only take rational values of $\epsilon$, so that the first intersection will be countable as well.

The sets you want to take the preimages of should be $(1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$, right?

@noam.szyfer Yes, of course. No idea what happened to me here. Thanks.

Firstly, the tail $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}_{\infty}$ should
be defined by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{A}_{\infty} & = & \cap_{k=1}^{\infty}\sigma(X_{k},X_{k+1},\ldots)\\
 & = & \cap_{k=1}^{\infty}\sigma(\cup_{n\geq k}\sigma(X_{n})).
\end{eqnarray*}
If we define $\mathcal{A}_{\infty}=\limsup_{k}\sigma(X_{k})=\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}\cup_{n\geq k}\sigma(X_{n})$,
it is problematic because $\cup_{n\geq k}\sigma(X_{n})$ needs not
be a $\sigma$-algebra. Denote $\mathcal{G}_{k}=\sigma(X_{k},X_{k+1},\ldots)$.
We go to show that $\limsup_{n}X_{n}$ is $\mathcal{A}_{\infty}$-measurable.
Let $k_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\limsup_{n}X_{n} & = & \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sup_{n\geq k}X_{n}\right)\\
 & = & \inf_{k\geq k_{0}}\left(\sup_{n\geq k}X_{n}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
For each $k\geq k_{0}$, clearly $\sup_{n\geq k}X_{n}$ is $\mathcal{G}_{k_{0}}$-measurable,
so $\inf_{k\geq k_{0}}\left(\sup_{n\geq k}X_{n}\right)$ is also $\mathcal{G}_{k_{0}}$-measurable.
Since $k_{0}$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $\limsup_{n}X_{n}$
is $\cap_{k}\mathcal{G}_{k}$-measurable. That is, $\limsup_{n}X_{n}$
is $\mathcal{A}_{\infty}$-measurable.
Similarly, $\liminf_{n}X_{n}$ is $\mathcal{A}_{\infty}$-measurable.
Finally, $\{\omega\mid\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{n}(\omega)=1\}=\{\omega\mid\limsup_{n}X_{n}(\omega)=1\}\cap\{\omega\mid\liminf_{n}X_{n}(\omega)=1\}\in\mathcal{A}_{\infty}.$

I think I am missing some basics, why does $\liminf_n Xn \in \mathcal{A}{\infty}$ imply that ${\omega | \liminf{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=1}\in\mathcal{A}_{\infty}$?

Denote $Y=\liminf_{n}X_{n}$. Are you able to prove that: if $Y$
is $\mathcal{A}{\infty}$-measurable, then ${\omega\mid Y(\omega)=1}\in\mathcal{A}{\infty}$
?
